# Parse an XML response from an HTTP POST with PHP?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, validation, http-post

I have this HTTP Post function in php which sends a form to a competition webservice, the response is an XML which gives further details if the entry was successful or not, how can I parse the results to capture the status field and give further feedback to the user?

Here is the code used:

```
<?php
$url = "...webserviceurl...";
$body = "userName=".$_POST["username"]."&password=".........;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-      urlencoded")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 
print $result;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can parse XML using SimpleXML or XML Parser.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP DOMDocument library and DOMXpath libraries to run xpath queries on the XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($result);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//Error)'); // echo contents of <Error> ... </Error> node
```

If the response has an XML namespace that is unusual (like some APIs tend to do), you have to register the namespace and prefix all queries with it.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('ns', 'https://namespace.org/namespace');
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//ns:Error)');
```

Comment: Hi Kingcoyote, thanks for your reply. unfrotunetly it's not working correctly, nothing is showing up, tried many fields but nothing is being captured. I'm also unable to prevent the "$result = curl_exec ($ch);" from popping in the browser window!!!! is there a way to prevent the curl_exec from popping?

Comment: Add this to your code: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true) to stop it from coming to the screen.

Comment: Excellent, that took care of the pop, thanks King, that's one bridge down, two more to go :)

Comment: ok I was able to capture the XML into a variable and print it's result: "$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);" this transformed into an array, not sure how to get only the status code only though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options built into PHP.  Try this one: [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Comment: Hi Cale, thanks for your reply, I tried that but nothing was captured , basically I tried this "$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);" then tried echo the result but nothing came out!

Comment: It returns an object, so you could use print_r to output the results.